# FXML variables are showing up as null despite using fx:ids

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am a beginner and I am trying to build a simple dictionary application.

I have a controller class which has a button to open a new dialog to input the various details.

The dialog is controlled by a separate controller and this is where I am experiencing problems, my FXML elements are given the value of null, hence I get a nullpointerexception when I run the code. I've annotated the FXML vaiables with @FXML and have checked that the fx:id in the fxml file matches that of the java file.

**Here is the Controller.java code:**

```
package sample;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Optional;

public class Controller {

@FXML
private BorderPane mainBorderPane;
@FXML
private DialogController controller = new DialogController();
@FXML
public void initialize(){

}

@FXML
public void newItemDialog(){
    Dialog <ButtonType> dialog = new Dialog<>();
    dialog.initOwner(mainBorderPane.getScene().getWindow());
    dialog.setTitle("Insert Word");
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("newDialog.fxml"));
    try{
        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(fxmlLoader.load());
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);
    dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CANCEL);
    Optional<ButtonType> result = dialog.showAndWait();
    if(result.isPresent() && result.get() == ButtonType.OK){
        boolean results = controller.processResults();

    }else{
        System.out.println("Cancelled");
        return;
    }
}
}
```

**Here is the DialogController.java code:**

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import sample.control.Data;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Optional;

public class DialogController {
@FXML
private TextField nameField;
@FXML
private TextField descriptionField;
@FXML
private TextField typeField;
@FXML
private TextField sentenceField;


@FXML
public boolean processResults() {

    String name = nameField.getText();
    String description = descriptionField.getText();
    String type = typeField.getText();
    String sentence = sentenceField.getText();

    return Data.getInstance().addWord(name,type,description,sentence);
    }    
}
```

**Here is the sample.fxml code:**

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<BorderPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
        xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
        fx:id ="mainBorderPane">

<top>
    <MenuBar>

        <Menu fx:id="fileButton" text="File">
            <MenuItem fx:id="newButton" onAction="#newItemDialog" text="New"/>
            <MenuItem fx:id="updateButton" text="Update"/>
            <MenuItem fx:id="deleteButton" text="Delete"/>
            <MenuItem fx:id="saveButton" text="Save"/>
        </Menu>
        <Menu fx:id="viewButton" text="View">
            <MenuItem text="Dark Mode"/>
        </Menu>
    </MenuBar>
</top>
<left>
    <ListView fx:id="wordListView" BorderPane.alignment="TOP_LEFT" prefHeight="Infinity" prefWidth="250">

    </ListView>
</left>
<center>
    <VBox>
        <TextArea fx:id = "wordDetails" prefWidth="Infinity" prefHeight="400">

        </TextArea>
        <TextArea prefWidth="Infinity" prefHeight="200">

        </TextArea>
    </VBox>
</center>

</BorderPane>
```

**Here is the newDialog.fxml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DialogPane?>
<DialogPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
        xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
        fx:controller="sample.DialogController"
        prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
<headerText>
    Enter A Word
</headerText>
<content>
    <VBox>
        <TextField fx:id="nameField" promptText="Enter the word"/>
        <TextField fx:id="typeField" promptText="Enter the type"/>
        <TextField fx:id="descriptionField" promptText="Enter a description"/>
        <TextField fx:id="sentenceField" promptText="Enter a sentence"/>
    </VBox>
</content>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Each `Controller` should have it's own `FXML` file

Comment: Simply creating a instance of a controller does not result in any of the fields from a fxml that uses this controller's class name as value for the `fx:controller` attribute being injected to the newly created controller instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@FXML` annotation indicates a field that should be initialized by the `FXMLLoader` to reference objects created corresponding to elements in an FXML file when the FXML file is loaded. Consequently:

1. It only makes sense to annotate fields `@FXML` if they correspond to elements in the FXML file
2. It **never** makes sense to initialize a field if it is annotated `@FXML` (because the `FXMLLoader` is supposed to initialize it)

Your `DialogController` field

```
@FXML
private DialogController controller = new DialogController();
```

doesn't make sense for both of these reasons: there is no `DialogController` element in the `sample.fxml`, and if there were, there would be no point in initializing the field.

A controller is a *specific object* associated with the UI loaded from an FXML file. The association is made by the `FXMLLoader` when it loads the FXML file. If you load the FXML file multiple times (as you appear to do here, since you are loading `newDialog.fxml` in an event handler), then (of course) you get new instances of all the elements in the FXML each time, and consequently a new instance of the controller class each time.

The object you create with

```
@FXML private DialogController controller = new DialogController();
```

is not the controller for any UI loaded any of the times you load `newDialog.fxml`; it is just another object of the same class. It is not clear whether you expect this field to somehow reference the controller created the first time the user chooses `"New"` from the menu, or the one created the second time they choose that menu item, etc. Or, of course, how you would expect it to refer to any of those controllers when you are initializing it before you ever load `newDialog.fxml`.

You get the controller from the `FXMLLoader` after loading the FXML. So you just need:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private BorderPane mainBorderPane;
    @FXML
    public void initialize(){

    }

    @FXML
    public void newItemDialog(){
        Dialog <ButtonType> dialog = new Dialog<>();
        dialog.initOwner(mainBorderPane.getScene().getWindow());
        dialog.setTitle("Insert Word");
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("newDialog.fxml"));
        try{
            dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(fxmlLoader.load());
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CANCEL);
        Optional<ButtonType> result = dialog.showAndWait();

        DialogController controller = fxmlLoader.getController();

        if(result.isPresent() && result.get() == ButtonType.OK){
            boolean results = controller.processResults();

        }else{
            System.out.println("Cancelled");
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you James! You have no idea how long I've tried to rectify this error.